# Propensity scores and patient comparability

Tags: propensity-scores

I have two groups of patients who underwent a surgery using method A or method B. The first group are patients who were operated in 1980's and 1990's only with method A. The second group are patients operated recently with mostly method B, but also in some cases A. In addition to that, I have various variables about patients (gender, age, medical indicators, etc.) that capture the pre-operation medical history and types of symptoms that patient developed.

The goal of the study is to compare the "effecitveness" of methods A and B in terms of patients' survival times after operation.

Somewhat different patients (in terms of age, gender, etc.) are operated with A and B. For example, quite some more older people were operated with B than with A. I want to used propensity score matching to balance the data.

My question is:

Does it make sense to estimate propensity scores (method ~ age + gender + ...) and use them for creating a matched dataset for further analysis (e.g. Cox regression)?

In particular, is it a problem that for patients in the first group method B was not yet available, so none of them could potentially received the alternative treatment?

Comment: First you need to carefully define _what the "effectiveness" metric will be_.

Comment: What is 80' and 90'? Does this stand for minutes?

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos, patients were followed for several years. I want to compare survival times.

Comment: @Momo, patients were operated in 1980's and 1990's.

Comment: No it is not a problem that method B was not available. This fact does not affect any inference related to survival times. You are not trying to explain "why they chose A over B", but _given the choice_ (for whatever reason), what was the survival time.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos, thanks. That partly confirms my intuition. However, isn't it a problem for estimating propensity scores (PS)? Given that this is an observational study, the goal of PS is to statistically reconostruct the assignment process to methods A and B. And for the first group, all where assigned to A because B was not available. Would not that distort the propensity scores?

Comment: Indeed you are right on that, but now I am confused: I thought that you wanted to compare the two methods in terms of their effectiveness. I understand now that "effectiveness" will be an _explanatory_ variable in order to see how it affects the propensity to assign A or B? In that case, the whole first sample should not be considered, in my opinion, because it is irrelevant to the object of study, if the object of study is the comparative construction of PS -"faced with two options how do we decide which one?". For the first group of patients there was no "dilemma".

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos, the goal is to compare methods A and B in terms of patient survival. I updated my question. I want to use propensity score matching to deal with the problem that somwhat different patients (in terms of age, gender and so on) are treated by the two methods. For example the newer method B is used on older patients which were not operate at all earlier. The question is then, whether balancing data with PS I can use the first group of patients, who were operated some time ago and only with method A.

Comment: The fact most of the A surgeries occurred decades earlier than the B surgeries could imply that you can't really compare the two. The fact the time period is so radically different can cause significant confounding. Other seemingly unrelated treatments and life in general has changed a lot over such a long period, which will also reflect on your survival results. **Don't underestimate this hurdle.**

Comment: Thanks everybody for the comments. Will somebody propose an answer? @AlecosPapadopoulos?